# python datatable read expression from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-datatable

I am using python's [datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I have 2 csv files.

CSV 1

```
A,B
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

CSV 2

```
NAME,EXPR
A_GREATER_THAN_B, A>B
A_GREATER_THAN_10, A>10
B_GREATER_THAN_5, B>5
```

Expected Output

```
A,B,A_GREATER_THAN_B,A_GREATER_THAN_10,B_GREATER_THAN_5
1,2,0,0,0
3,4,0,0,0
5,6,0,0,1
```

Code

```
exprdt = dt.fread("csv_2.csv")
exprdict = dict(exprdt.to_tuples())
dt1[:, dt.update(**exprdict)]
print(dt1)
```

Current output

```
   |     A      B      C   A_G_B          A_G_1     B_G_4   
   | int32  int32  int32   str32          str32     str32   
-- + -----  -----  -----   -------------  --------  --------
 0 |     0      1      1   dt.f.A>dt.f.B  dt.f.A>1  dt.f.B>4
 1 |     1      5      6   dt.f.A>dt.f.B  dt.f.A>1  dt.f.B>4
```

I am trying to use the [extend](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/transform_data.html?highlight=extend#extend) function to process first datatable using the expressions from second datatable. When i use fread to read the csv files, the expression is processed as string and not as expression.

How do i use the 2nd datatable (csv) to update the first datatable using the NAME and EXPR columns?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output? Am I right in assuming you expect something like `A_GREATER_THAN_B, False` for the first line of the second table? Note that `datatable` is not "Python's", it is a third party library that users need to install to be able to use your script - are you using it for a specific reason, or were you mistakenly thinking it was standard Python. I have nothing against it, but if all you need is a list or an array, you may want to steer clear - or use something that better aligns with wherever you want to use the result? (you may have a good reason)

Comment: I have added the output i am trying to achieve. I am trying to use datatable instead of dataframe.

Comment: I feel it would be easier to get csv2 as a dictionary, then build your expression, that you can pass to `if else` to get you desired output

Comment: Yes, i can convert the 2nd csv to dict but still the value will be of datatype string and not an expression.

Comment: kindly share the dictionary, let's see. If you can find a way to attach datatable's `f` function , you are half way there

Comment: looks unnecessarily complicated though; you still need to convert the `>` to an operator (operator.gt) or some other way

Comment: I feel you're making it very hard on yourself, by having expressions as text in your data, needing to evaluate those expressions against the column names in another table, whilst using a library that doesn't directly support text expressions like these - what have you tried yourself so far? Is the solution you propose required in all its complexity and flexibility?

Comment: pandas dataframe eval is an option. i am looking for similar functionality in datatable and my ony problem is converting string to FExpr.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do what you want, but just that you can do something doesn't mean it's a good idea. Any solution that requires `eval()` is probably more complicated than it needs to be, and introduces great risks if you don't have complete control over the data going in.

Having said that, this script shows a naive approach without fancy expressions from a table, and the approach you suggest - which I strongly recommend you not use and figure out a better way to achieve what you need:

```
from io import StringIO
import re
import datatable as dt

csv1 = """A,B
1,2
3,4
5,6"""

csv2 = """NAME,EXPR
A_GREATER_THAN_B, A>B
A_GREATER_THAN_10, A>10
B_GREATER_THAN_5, B>5"""


def naive():
    # naive approach
    d = dt.fread(StringIO(csv1))
    d['A_GREATER_THAN_B'] = d[:, dt.f.A > dt.f.B]
    d['A_GREATER_THAN_10'] = d[:, dt.f.A > 10]
    d['B_GREATER_THAN_5'] = d[:, dt.f.B > 5]

    print(d)


def update_with_expressions(d, expressions):
    for n in range(expressions.nrows):
        col = expressions[n, :][0, 'NAME']
        expr = re.sub('([A-Za-z]+)', r'dt.f.\1', expressions[n, :][0, 'EXPR'])
        # here's hoping that expression is trustworthy...
        d[col] = d[:, eval(expr)]


def fancy():
    # fancy, risky approach
    d = dt.fread(StringIO(csv1))
    update_with_expressions(d, dt.fread(StringIO(csv2)))
    print(d)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    naive()
    fancy()
```

Result (showing you get the same result from either approach):

```
   |     A      B  A_GREATER_THAN_B  A_GREATER_THAN_10  B_GREATER_THAN_5
   | int32  int32             bool8              bool8             bool8
-- + -----  -----  ----------------  -----------------  ----------------
 0 |     1      2                 0                  0                 0
 1 |     3      4                 0                  0                 0
 2 |     5      6                 0                  0                 1
[3 rows x 5 columns]

   |     A      B  A_GREATER_THAN_B  A_GREATER_THAN_10  B_GREATER_THAN_5
   | int32  int32             bool8              bool8             bool8
-- + -----  -----  ----------------  -----------------  ----------------
 0 |     1      2                 0                  0                 0
 1 |     3      4                 0                  0                 0
 2 |     5      6                 0                  0                 1
[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Note: if someone knows of a nicer way to iterate over rows in a `datatable.Frame`, please leave a comment, because I'm not a fan of this part:

```
    for n in range(expressions.nrows):
        col = expressions[n, :][0, 'NAME']
```

Note that `StringIO` is only imported to have the .csv files in the code, you wouldn't need them.